# How to make transaction mode manual in Revit Extensions (REX) platform?

Tags: c#, revit-api

I am using REX to develop an extension. But I see the default transaction mode is set to automatic.

Is it possible to make transaction manual without causing any problem with the functionality of REX classes?

Is it possible to make transaction mode, partially manual (e.g. changing the transactionmode attribute for ExtensionRevit class only)?

Comment: Changing transaction attribute to manual for ExtensionRevit class result in error saying a transaction is already begun. I changed transaction mode to manual for DirectRevitAccess and ExtensionDirectRevitAccess classes. I don't know why there two transaction attributes but now it seems the transaction mode is manual and my extension is working well. No apparent consequences yet..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discussed this question with the development team. They explained that it is possible to switch to manual transaction in REX modules and it shouldn’t cause any problem with REX classes. The required changes are in the in source code generated by the VS template and are only inside DirectRevitAccess.cs, where you need to switch the mode to manual and add the calls to create, start and commit the transaction.